# Another complicated problem on probabilitic conditioning.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

The real random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have a uniform distribution $U([0,1])$. Find:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ (X-Y)^2|XY \right]$$

Solution:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ (X-Y)^2|XY \right]=\mathbb{E}\left[ X^2-2XY+Y^2|XY \right]=2\mathbb{E}[X^2|XY]-2XY$$
What to do next I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\mathrm dy\int_0^1\mathrm dx\,(x-y)^2\delta(xy-s)
&=
\int_0^1\mathrm dy\int_0^1\mathrm dx\,(x-y)^2\frac1y\delta\left(x-\frac sy\right)\\
&=
\int_s^1\mathrm dy\,\left(\frac sy-y\right)^2\frac1y\\
&=
\int_s^1\mathrm dy\,\left(\frac{s^2}{y^3}-2\frac sy+y\right)\\
&=
\left[-\frac12\frac{s^2}{y^2}-2s\log y+\frac12y^2\right]_s^1\\
&=
-\frac12s^2+\frac12+\frac12+2s\log s-\frac12s^2\\
&=
2s\log s-s^2+1
\end{align}

and
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\mathrm dy\int_0^1\mathrm dx\,\delta(xy-s)
&=
\int_0^1\mathrm dy\int_0^1\mathrm dx\,\frac1y\delta\left(x-\frac sy\right)\\
&=
\int_s^1\mathrm dy\,\frac1y\\
&=
-\log s\;.
\end{align}

So

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ (X-Y)^2\mid XY=s\right]=\frac{s^2-1}{\log s}-2s\;.
$$

[Here's a plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28s%5E2%20-%201%29%20%2F%20log%20s%20-%202s%20for%20s%3D0..1).